# How to install snmp in ASIANUX Server 7 offline?

Tags: linux, centos-7, rpm, snmp, snmpwalk

I am working with ASIANUX Server7 machine offline and I need to install snmp.
In fact, I downloaded **net-snmp-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64.rpm** from other machine and I copied it to the ASIANUX machine and I tried to install it with:

```
rpm -i net-snmp-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I got this error:

```
warning: net-snmp-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY'                                                                   
error: Failed dependencies:
libnetsnmpagent.so.31()(64bit) is needed by net-snmp-1:5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64
libnetsnmpmibs.so.31()(64bit) is needed by net-snmp-1:5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64
libnetsnmptrapd.so.31()(64bit) is needed by net-snmp-1:5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64
net-snmp-agent-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7 is needed by net-snmp-1:5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64
net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7 is needed by net-snmp-1:5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64
```

So I downloaded the **net-snmp-agent-libs-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64.rpm** and I tried to install it with:

```
rpm -i net-snmp-agent-libs-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I got this error:

```
warning: net-snmp-agent-libs-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY"error: Failed dependencies: net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7 is needed by net-snmp-agent-libs-1:5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64
```

So I downloaded the **net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-49.el7_9.2.x86_64.rpm** file and I tried to install it with:

```
rpm -i net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-49.el7_9.2.x86_64.rpm
```

but I got this error:

```
warning: net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-49.el7_9.2.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
file /usr/lib64/libnetsnmp.so.31.0.2 from install of net-snmp-libs-1:5.7.2-49.el7_9.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package net-snmp-libs-1:5.7.2-28.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt from install of net-snmp-libs-1:5.7.2-49.el7_9.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package net-snmp-libs-1:5.7.2-28.el7.x86_64
```

***Note:***
I have no internet access, that means, I should install snmp offline

Thank you all for your support

Comment: You are playing whack-a-mole, but try installing them all at once, as in `rpm -Uh net-snmp-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64.rpm net-snmp-agent-libs-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64.rpm`. And keep on adding them until it works. Alternatively, download all the packages and create your own repository.